# Combining FailoverCCF and CachingCCF in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, tcpclient

I'm trying to combine FailoverCCF with CachingCCF without success these far.
Here is what I've tried:

```
FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientConnectionFactory = new FailoverClientConnectoinFactory(underlyingCF());
failoverClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true); // this is because CachingClient connection factory will force the singleUse = true

public List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> underlyingCF() {
    return Arrays.asList(servers).stream().map(svr -> {
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNio = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(server, port);
        tcpNio.setSingleUse(false);
        return CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNio, 8);
    }).collect(toList());

}
```

Variable servers is initialized as:

```
String[] servers = new String[]{"local","localhost"};
```

However, when it failed to connect to the first server, it doesn't try to the second server. If I dont't use CachingCCF, it failover to the second server.

Spring integration version: 4.1.4.RELEASE
Spring framework version: 4.1.6.RELEASE

Here is the stacktrace (content of the message are removed)

```
2015-07-19 00:26:44,877 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.TcpOutboundGateway - outboundClient received message: GenericMessage [payload={}, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@569348e1, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@569348e1, id=ddf4e460-6829-c784-db09-d78162051530, json__TypeId__=class com.mycompany.app.client.request.RequestObject, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1437236804876}]
2015-07-19 00:26:44,878 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - Opening new socket connection to local:20000
2015-07-19 00:27:06,330 [main] ERROR o.s.i.i.t.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:449) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:647) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.buildNewConnection(TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.java:83) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainNewConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:101) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:63) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 79 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain connection; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:58) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:133) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection.findAConnection(FailoverClientConnectionFactory.java:199) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection.<init>(FailoverClientConnectionFactory.java:172) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(FailoverClientConnectionFactory.java:110) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:115) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:321) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:298) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:414) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:374) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

In Linux, the exception is even different

```
2015-08-06 10:41:22,850 [main] ERROR o.s.i.i.t.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.buildNewConnection(TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.java:83) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainNewConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:101) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection.findAConnection(FailoverClientConnectionFactory.java:199) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection.<init>(FailoverClientConnectionFactory.java:172) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(FailoverClientConnectionFactory.java:110) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:63) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 84 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain connection; nested exception is java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:58) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(CachingClientConnectionFactory.java:133) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:115) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:286) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:321) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:298) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:414) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:374) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getReferenceData(Unknown Source) [na:na]
at com.jpmorgan.cm.tpm.refdata.client.ReferenceDataServiceImpl.getHolidayCalendar(ReferenceDataServiceImpl.java:54) [tpm-ref-data-client-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.jpmorgan.cm.tpm.refdata.client.ReferenceDataServiceImpl.getHolidayCalendar(ReferenceDataServiceImpl.java:48) [tpm-ref-data-client-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.jpmorgan.cm.tpm.refdata.client.FailoverIT.should_failover_to_second_server(FailoverIT.java:55) [test-classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252) [surefire-junit4-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141) [surefire-junit4-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112) [surefire-junit4-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189) [surefire-api-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165) [surefire-booter-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85) [surefire-booter-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115) [surefire-booter-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75) [surefire-booter-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
```

Comment: You should share the problem with us, e.g. StackTrace or describe what's wrong. We have this test in the Framework, BTW: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/TcpOutboundGatewayTests.java#L508

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say what my problem is. I've updated the question now. I'll try to provide the stacktrace later.

Comment: The Spring Integration version, please, and DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework` would be great

Comment: Please, try to make `singleUse` the same for all `connectionFactories`. Follow with the *NOTE* from here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ip.html#failover-cf

Comment: All `connectionFactories` are having the same `singleUse` property. Otherwise the test won't even start.

Comment: Yes, I got it! And have just reproduced your issue. We will check the algorithm Gary tomorrow. Right now I only can say that we don't handle the *unconnected* case from the `CachingCF` but just only `IOException` in the `FailoverCF`, when we can connect to the target `CF` but  can't send a packet to the socket. Looks like a bug, but let Gary know about your issue and his wisdom can help us.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I can see from the test you shared, it is handling at the send function, but not at connect function. I'll wait for your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought we had tested both caching failover and failover caching, but it seems we only support the former (caching failover)...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/848

Is there any reason you can't wire up the factories that way?

Please open a JIRA issue so we can either support both ways, or at least detect the configuration that doesn't work.

Comment: There is no reason, it's just naturally that I had used the cachingCCF and wanted to make it support failover, so I applied failover to the cachingCCF. I'll try if my test works for caching the failover tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: If I use caching failover instead of failover caching, the cachingCCF will force failoverCCF's `singleUse` to `true` and therefore the underlying `tcpNio`'s `singleUse` has to be `true` as well. This will effectively forcing all CFs to set `singleUse` to `true`. Is this expected? Won't the underlying `tcpNio` be opening and closing the connection in this case?
To make it even more complicated, if I'm using this CF on TcpReceivingChannelAdapter as client-mode, this CF's `singleUse` must be set to `false`. So I can't use the above scenario (caching failover).

Comment: Hmmm - good point - we've rewritten the self-closing stuff in 4.2 so that connections don't close themselves (it was too confusing). Now the adapters are responsible for "closing" single-use connections. So it should work ok with 4.2; I don't think it will be easy to fix in earlier versions.

Comment: Apart from `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` as client-mode, your suggested configuration is working with my test case. I'll accept this answer and open JIRA issue to support both ways

Comment: Single-use means the factory creates a new socket each time - so no, with a CCCF in the middle, they shouldn't be closed but, I think it will work because ultimately, the close is delegated up to the CCCF which returns the connection to the cache instead of actually pushing the close back down to the socket.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the explanation.

I've open JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3795 for this issue

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but it behaves differently between Windows and Linux. The failover (doesn't matter with/out Caching) failed in Linux. I'm updating the question with the stacktrace